# RedirectMatch adding extra url segments

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect requests for our old blog to a new url on a subdomain.
The old url looks like

`https://www.website.com/blog-name/post/slug-of-the-title`

and it needs to redirect to

`https://stage.website.com/blog-name/slug-of-the-title`

I'm using this rule in my .htaccess

`RedirectMatch ^/blog-name/post/(.*)$ https://stage.website.com/blog-name/$1`

And I'm getting redirected to the correct page, but my urls have extra segments on the end. Like

`https://stage.website.com/blog-name/slug-of-the-title/?/blog-name/post/slug-of-the-title`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Make sure you keep these rules at the top of your .htaccess rules file(in case you have any more rules also in your .htaccess file).

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog-name/post/(.*)/?$ https://stage.website.com/blog-name/$1? [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: This works, but it definitely has to be above my other rules.  Thanks a bunch @RavinderSingh13!